# SELECT clause with a DATETIME column in Sybase 15

Tags: datetime, select, sybase, where-clause

I'm trying to do a query like this on a table with a DATETIME column.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_date = 
2011-03-06T15:53:34.890-05:00
```

I have the following as an string input from an external source:

2011-03-06T15:53:34.890-05:00

I need to perform a query on my database table and extract the row which contains this same date. In my database it gets stored as a DATETIME and looks like the following:

2011-03-06 15:53:34.89

I can probably manipulate the outside input slightly ( like strip off the -5:00 ). But I can't figure out how to do a simple select with the datetime column.

I found the convert function, and style 123 seems to match my needs but I can't get it to work. Here is the link to reference about style 123

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks125.htm

Answer (score 3):

I think that convert's slightly wrongly documented in that version of the docs.

Because this format always has century I think you only need use 23.  Normally the 100 range for convert adds the century to the year format.

That format only goes down to seconds what's more.

If you want more you'll need to past together 2 x converts.  That is, past a ymd part onto a convert(varchar, datetime-column, 14) and compare with your trimmed string.  milliseconds comparison is likely to be a problem depending on where you got your big time string though because the Sybase binary stored form has a granularity of 300ms I think, so if your source string is from somewhere else it's not likely to compare.  In other words - strip the milliseconds and compare as strings.

So maybe:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE convert(varchar,the_date,23) =
'2011-03-06T15:53:34'

But the convert on the column would prevent the use of an index, if that's a problem.

If you compare as datetimes then the convert is on the rhs - but you have to know what your milliseconds are in the_date.  Then an index can be used.